# Вернуть JS из ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

Есть скрипт

```
function ajax_info_window(value) {
    var div_result = "ajax_info_window_result";

    nocache = Math.random();

    http.open('get', '/vk_iframe/scripts/ajax_info_window.php?&id=' + value + '&nocache=' + nocache);
    http.onreadystatechange = loginReply;
    http.send(null);

    function loginReply() {
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
            var response = http.responseText;

            if (response != '') {
                document.getElementById(div_result).innerHTML = response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Работает как надо , но хочу чтобы она вернула JS код который выполнится, как реализовать подскажите пожалуйста, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать тег `<script>` записать в него ваш ответ, разрешить его выполнение defer=true, вставить в дом и можно использовать.

Answer (score 0):

если ответ чистый джаваскрипт то можете воспользоваться функ-ей eval но это очень очень не советуется.

Answer (score 0):

В библиотеке jQuery есть функция

```
$.getScript('visible/js/file.js');
```

Если ответ сервера это валидный js то у вас получится то что вам нужно. Эту функцию думаю можно как-то вырвать в отдельности если не хотите подключать всю библиотеку.

Comment: выдрать такую не простую функцию из jquery, полностью сохранив ее работоспособность, не простоя задача. Нужно выдирать весь блок отвечающий за аякс, легче дописать этот код.